# ImportError: No module named misago

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I get this error while installing Misago the forum. I don't know what's causing since I have Django installed. Please help me anyone.

```
xxxxx@xxxxx:~/Desktop/newfeed/startupindia$ python manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 23, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/home/xxxxx/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 350, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/home/xxxxx/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 324, in execute
django.setup()
File "/home/xxxxx/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "/home/xxxxx/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
File "/home/xxxxx/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
module = import_module(entry)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
ImportError: No module named misago
```

Comment: You seem to have included `misago` in your `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`. See if it misspelled or incorrectly configured.

Comment: Are you sure that you install by python2.7 pip? Maybe you have python3 too and your pip3 overwrote the pip2.7 which pointed to pip.

Comment: xxxxx@xxxx:~/Desktop$ python -V                                                                  
Python 2.7.12
xxxxx@xxxx:~/Desktop$ pip -V                                                                       
pip 8.1.1 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)

Comment: @Nitesh Singh based on your next [next question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42671091/importerror-the-imagingft-c-module-is-not-installed-misago), I assume you've got it a step further. Please accept an answer if one of them gave you the right directions, or post the solution to the problem if you've found out the right solution yourself. In that way you can help any other users facing the same problem.

Comment: thank you @Nrzonline you post solution to the problem.                                 I get this error while creating superuser Misago the forum. (Ubuntu 16.04).

ImportError: The _imagingft C module is not installed . ( Misago )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't heard of Misago before, however from the documentations:

**Version ~0.5.5 Alpha 1**

[Misago documentation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Misago/0.5.5a1)

Misago is delivered with [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/).
Vagrant is a Virtual Machine, and can be started with the `vagrant up` command from the root directory.

All the required installations will be done with an installation script being executed on the `vagrant up` command.

[Vagrant: What, Why and How?](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/vagrant-what-why-and-how--net-26500)

**Version 0.6 Alpha 1**

The Misago version 0.6 Alpha 1 from [GitHub](https://github.com/rafalp/Misago/blob/master/README.rst) does not contain vagrant, but is installed with an install script:

> Development
>   To start Misago site locally, first setup and activate virtual  environment for it and then fire following commands:

```
python setup.py install
```

More about the [virtual envirionment](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/).

To test and run the server:

```
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py createsuperuser
python manage.py runserver
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you didn't set the environment variable. first of type into terminal

```
virtualenv env
source env/bin/activate
```

then try `pip freeze` 
if misago is missing here then install misago again.